# Numpy numbers arent integers?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain why some Numpy numbers aren't whole integers?
When I run this:

```
print(np.sqrt(2.)**2)
```

I get:

```
 2.0000000000000004
```

And why is it that I get

```
[ 0.          1.11111111  2.22222222  3.33333333  4.44444444  5.55555556

 6.66666667  7.77777778  8.88888889 10.        ]
```

when I print

```
print(np.linspace(0, 10, 10))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

From numpy's documentation:

```
    dtype : dtype, optional
        The type of the output array.  If `dtype` is not given, the data type
        is inferred from `start` and `stop`. The inferred dtype will never be
        an integer; `float` is chosen even if the arguments would produce an
        array of integers.
```

This can be overridden by explicitly specifying `dtype`:

```
np.linspace(0, 10, 10, dtype=np.int64)
> array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 10])
```

Comment: But why would they even produce an array of floats? I don't get the point

Comment: Perhaps to make the API more generic, and leave round-up / round-down to the user